# How to add custom verb (http request method ) to rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want to add custom http VERB to rails 4 
here is my routes.rb

```
ring "/session/" => "calls#ringing"
```

and I also puts this code to initializers

```
%w(ring busy).each do |method|                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  ActionDispatch::Request::HTTP_METHODS << method.upcase                                                                                                                                                                                    
  ActionDispatch::Request::HTTP_METHOD_LOOKUP[method.upcase] = method.to_sym                                                                                                                                                                
end
```

When I try to start application I have this error.

```
undefined method `ring' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000000035c4150>
```

I really need to use this custom verb "RING".

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding to routes this string

match '/session/:sessionid', :to => 'calls#initiate', :via => :ring

Comment: can you just make up your own HTTP methods like that...? I mean it might work, but does it even make sense?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by adding to routes this string

```
match '/session/:sessionid', :to => 'calls#initiate', :via => :ring
```

Comment: please accept this answer (green check mark). That allows this Q&A to be referenced in flags for duplicates, etc. (THIS is not a dupe, but a question I am looking at elsewhere is)

Comment: Does anyone know how to make a custom HTTP request in Ruby/Rails?