# Add verbs to resources of Rails's routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-routing

By default, the `resources` keyword of Rails routing creates 7 actions.

For example with `resources :foos`:

```
-----------------------
| Verb      | Action  |
-----------------------
| GET       | index   |
| GET       | show    |
| GET       | edit    |
| GET       | new     |
| PUT/PATCH | update  |
| POST      | create  |
| DELETE    | destroy |
-----------------------
```

How can we add inside this list the `OPTIONS` verb such as:

```
--------------------------------
| Verb    | Action             |
--------------------------------
| ...     | ...                |
| OPTIONS | member_options     |
| OPTIONS | collection_options |
--------------------------------
```

**In other words**, by default, for each resource, we have to use something like this:

```
match    '/foos/',      via: :options, controller: 'foos', action: 'collection_options'
match    '/foos/:id/',  via: :options, controller: 'foos', action: 'member_options', as: :foo
resources :foos
```

Instead, I would prefer a custom settings in order to just do this:

```
resources :foos
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to include additional verbs, outside the standard set? It is possible to change the action for a verb, but IDK if you can add additional verbs.

Comment: I need to use `OPTIONS` verb for each resource, in order to build a RESTful service. The purpose of this issue is to DRY my routes.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065443/how-to-add-custom-verb-http-request-method-to-rails4

Comment: No, it's not the same issue.

Comment: it may not be the same issue but the core of answer is in there.  you can try creating your own routing method that includes those additional routes.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to avoid adding multiple match statements to my routes file just for the OPTIONS verb

Answer (score 0):

To avoid listing every path for the OPTIONS verb, you could add a [catch all route](http://railscasts.com/episodes/46-catch-all-route), e.g.

```
match '*path', to: 'application#cors_preflight_check', via: [:options]
```